# Does my ghusl count

Tags: ghusl

I got semen on my pubic hair. I tried to wash everything and get the semen out then done wudu. When I got changed I noticed solid white stuff on my pubic hair. Is my ghusl still valid in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Praise be to Allah,

You should start your Ghusl all over and also, Prophet Muhammad (s) ordered us to shave pubic hairs because impure substances stick to the public hairs and also because it is different from the practices of the non-believers and avoids bad smells. Prophet Muhammad (s) said,  “5 things are part of fitrah, circumcision, removing the pubic hair, clipping the fingernails, plucking the armpit hair and trimming the moustache” (Bukhari 5541 and Muslim 377) However shaving the armpit hair instead of plucking it is permissible if plucking it is to painful for one. Prophet Muhammad (s) set a time frame that one must not exceed 40 days without having any of these done as narrated in Muslim 379.

And Allah knows what is best and most correct.